# res.locals.user is not available in ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

NODE JS

I am having dashboard.ejs file and .js file.

I had set a variable in js file to locals but i cannot be able to access it in ejs file.

my Project is when user entered dashboard page he cannot able to access it untill he logs in.

Following are my files

```
dashboard.ejs
------------------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
      Welcome to dashboard, <b><%= user1.email %></b>     
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is my app.js file

```
 app.js
 --------
const express require('express');
const app = express();
const {requireAuth} = require('./authVerify');

app.get('/dashboard',requireAuth ,(req,res)=>{
       res.render('dashboard',{user1: res.locals.user1});
})
```

I has removed all other code and included only required ones.

requireAuth is in authverify file

```
authverify.js
--------------
const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.toke;

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, 'secret', async (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.redirect('/login');
      } else {
        console.log(decodedToken);
        let user = await User.findById(decodedToken._id);
        res.locals.user1 = user;
        console.log(res.locals.user1);
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
  next();
};
```

[I am getting this error when opened localhost:3000/dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd1Dr.png)

I am expecting my mail after Welcome message as shown in picture2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm8rS.png)

Comment: `res.locals` are globally available to template, You don't need to return it in `/dashboard` route. Try if removing it solves the issue.

Comment: I had tried it but stiff getting error

Answer (score 0):

here's the working code

```js
const setUserInfo = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;

    // making sure token exists in the cookies
    if (token) {
        // verify the token signature
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, decodedToken) => {
            // wrong jwt token ( token has been tampered with or has expired )
            // set user to null
            if (err) {
                res.locals.user = null;
                next();
            }
            // best case scenario ( everything is perfect )
            else {
                // find user in db, populate user info
                const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);
                res.locals.user = user;
                next();
            }
        });
    }
    // if token does not exist in cookies, then set user to null, and go to next middleware
    else {
        res.locals.user = null;
        next();
    }
};
```